# Read from Custom List Object

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have enteries inside an Sqlite Database and a method defined as follows:

// Getting All ComplainMessageWhatevers
public List getAllComplainMessageWhatever() {

```
List<ComplainMessageWhatever> cmwList = new ArrayList<ComplainMessageWhatever>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLAIN_MESSAGE_WHATEVER;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        ComplainMessageWhatever cmw = new ComplainMessageWhatever();
        cmw.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        cmw.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        cmw.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
        // Adding cmw to list
        cmwList.add(cmw);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return cmw list
return cmwList;
```

}

In my activity, I do this:

```
  DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        List<ComplainMessageWhatever> d1 = dh.getAllComplainMessageWhatever();
```

Now I don't know how to extract values from that list, such as phone number, message, etc. and show them inside a RecyclerView(Mateiral Design Cards).

How can I do that? Should I post the DatabaseHandler class?

Comment: Write getter methods in you CMW class and access data using that methods

Answer (score 1):

As you have written setter methods in your custom class write getter methods similarly

**like -**

```
public int getId(){
 return id;
}
```

Write similar methods to access other data
And 
In your 'RecyclerView' adapters 'bindViewHolder' method first get a reference to your custom class object

**Like -**

```
YourCustomClass customClass = customclassList.get(position);

int id = customClass.getId()
```

And access other data similarly